# I need to extract data from multiple filled out pdfs

Tags: python

I need to extract data from multiple filled out `pdfs`, could somebody modify my answer.

```
from fillpdf import fillpdfs

import os

import glob

import pdfplumber

import PyPDF2

for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/Sam/OneDrive/Desktop/Pro/*.pdf"):
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        text = page.extract_text()
        text = " ".join(text.split())
        print(text)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the data? Are you just looking for the text from the first page of each PDF? Are you trying to save it to a file or use it later in the program?

The value "f" is a dictionary and it should have values corresponding to the filled-out values of each of the fields. For more information on Python dictionaries, see: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Answer (score 0):

Using *PDFplumber*, see the docs on GitHub: [Extracting Form values](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-form-values).

```py
import glob
import pdfplumber

def extract_text(pdf):
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text


def extract_form(pdf):
    if "AcroForm" not in pdf.doc.catalog.keys():
        return None
    form = pdf.doc.catalog["AcroForm"]
    form_data = {}
    for field in form["Fields"]:
        f = field.resolve()
        field_name = f["T"]
        field_value = f["V"] if 'V' in f.keys() else None
        form_data[field_name] = field_value
    return form_data


for file in glob.glob("output*.pdf"):
    print(f"- File: {file}")
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        text = extract_text(pdf)
        print(f"--- Text:\n{text}")
        form = extract_form(pdf)
        print(f"--- Form Data:\n{form}")
```

Prints:

```
- File: output_filled.pdf
--- Text:
First Name: Last Name: Street Address: Apt #: Zipcode: City: Spirit: Date: Evil: Language: Français Esperanto Latin Signature:
--- Form Data:
{b'Given Name Text Box': b'Hello', b'Family Name Text Box': b'World', b'Address 1 Text Box': b'\xfe\xff', b'City Text Box': b'\xfe\xff', b'Gender List Box': b'Panda', b'Height Formatted Field': None, b'Driving License Check Box': /'Off', b'Apt Number Text Box': b'\xfe\xff', b'Zipcode Text Box': b'\xfe\xff', b'Latin Check Box': /'Off', b'French Check Box': None, b'Esperanto Check Box': None, b'signature_1': None}
- File: output.pdf
--- Text:
First Name: Faye Last Name: Valentine Street Address: 223B Baker Street Apt #: 6F Zipcode: 94455 City: London Spirit: Panda Date: 12/04/19 Evil: Language: Français Esperanto Latin Signature:
--- Form Data:
None
```

Tested with files from [PDFjinja's example](https://github.com/rammie/pdfjinja/tree/master/examples):

1. manually filled out `sample.pdf` (has form data values)
2. the original `output.pdf` (has only text)

#### See also

May be of interest, related blog posts about filling:

- [Filling in PDF forms with Python](https://yoongkang.com/blog/pdf-forms-with-python/)
- [Filling PDF Forms with Python](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/22/filling-pdf-forms-with-python/)